# Function return true

Tags: vb.net, function, return

I'm trying to make a function that search for process passed in parameter and if exists return true yet it always returns false

```
Public Function ps_running(ByVal name As String) As Boolean 
    For Each Proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If Proc.ProcessName.StartsWith(name) AndAlso (name.Length <> 0)  Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Am sure it's something basic i'm missing but i can't tell what 
Thanks

Comment: The condition `Proc.ProcessName.StartsWith(name) AndAlso (name.Length <> 0)` is never true.

Comment: Move the length test above your for each loop. It is sufficient to only check it once. Secondly, make sure the ProcessName and the name have the same casing. Either convert all to lower case or try use the appropriate [CulturInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6k0axhx9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compare case insensitive.

Comment: even without testing the length it return false (to avoid empty inputs)
change both ToUpper , same

Comment: "I'm trying to make a function" > Chuck Norris does not try, he always succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
Sub Main()
    For Each Proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        Console.WriteLine(Proc.ProcessName)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine()

    Dim b As Boolean = ps_running("dwm")
    Console.WriteLine(b)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Function ps_running(ByVal name As String) As Boolean
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) Then Return False

    For Each Proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If Proc.ProcessName.ToUpper.StartsWith(name.ToUpper) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

Edited with full test

Comment: Funny because this works fine. I 've just edited the code with the full test.

Comment: Can you provide the list of processes and a more detailed example?

Comment: As i said i may be missing something easy this is a link to my project
it's in progress all i need to to do for now to check if process exist if not lunch it again from the path provided by user this is a link to download my project is pretty newbie but from the main form you get the idea :)

I marked your answer as correct cause am sure it is but i have problem somewhere in my code 

http://sharesend.com/ths7xw88

Comment: Stay strong Chuck! ;-D

Comment: :D you got to be B.Lee to help with this :p